# How to modify many to many field in wizard?

Tags: odoo

I have model contains many to many assign_to_id, I want to modify that field in wizard form through escalte_to method when user trigger escalate button

Model:

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    _name = 'itmangement.incident'
    assigned_to_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Assigned To",domain="[('department_id', '=', dep_id)]",required=True)
```

Wizard model

```
class Escalate(models.TransientModel):
    escalated_to = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Escalated To", required=True)

        @api.one
        def escalate(self):

            incident_obj = self.env['itmangement.incident']
            record = incident_obj.browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))
            record.write({'state': 'escalated'})
```

Comment: You want to modify the Many2Many that is in the form from a wizard?, do you raise this wizard from the Model of the assigned_to_id field?

Comment: yes, I want to modify the many2many field from wizard through escalte_to when user trigger escalate button

Comment: Can you specify a bit more? i mean, you complete the wizard with escalated_to and you want to parse that record it in the many2many field of the form?, why you use a Many2many? isnt a One2many enough?. If you specify a bit more of what exactly and why you need to do it ill help you with the code

Answer (score 1):

```
class Escalate(models.TransientModel):
    escalated_to = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Escalated To", required=True)

    @api.one
    def escalate(self):

        object_id = self.env.context.get('active_id')

        for object in self.env['itmangement.incident'].browse(object_id) and self.escalated_to:

            object.assigned_to_id = self.escalated_to.id
```

Comment: an error raised:
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Incident Management Process - itmangement.incident]

Comment: Maybe you need to complete a field that is required in itmangement.incident? try to check what the log says